# Linux and DD - Infinite time to extract one file

Tags: linux, extract, dd

I use `dd` on Linux to extract data from a tape (yeah it's really oldschool!) and I had a problem. Sometimes, when I extract a file (from different files on one tape), after a really long time and a really big size of the file extract, the extraction is still not finished.
So it's a problem because I know that the size of the file is about 10MB and not 1GB or more.
I know the number of blocks in the file (4092 for example) so I would like to stop the extraction at this number of blocks.
Do you know if it's possible to stop the extraction at 4092 blocks for example?

I have searched for a long time on the Internet and I haven't found a command about this.

I use this command to extract files from a tape:

```
sudo mt -f /dev/nst0 of=file.out bs=512 conv=noerror,sync
```

Comment: use `count=` parameter - count x bs = total size, see man page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "count" option to dd to specify the number of blocks to copy; combined with the blocksize option, "bs", this allows you to control the amount of data being extracted. Note that a smaller blocksize may also result in a longer transfer time, depending on the kind of device.

First position the tape as required, e.g. to block 2048:

```
mt -f /dev/nst0 setblk 2048
```

Then use the dd command to read from the relevant device (note: there may be several similar tape devices, check the driver details to find the no-rewind device if you want to subsequently read other files):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/nst0 of=file.out bs=1024 count=37 conv=noerror,sync
```

This will read 37 Kilobytes from the starting position of block 2048 in blocks (i.e. buffers) of 1024 bytes each.

Comment: Thank's a lot ! I will try that !
I didn't think that option could solve my problem... thank's again :)